# Counting blank spaces, tabs and new lines in java without file handling

Tags: java, exception, runtime, bufferedreader, counting

This is the code I've written for counting the number of spaces, tabs and newlines in a string entered by the user(new line is marked by a full stop (".") and I'm doing this without file handling. 
This code is throwing a string out of bounds exception during runtime and I'm not able to figure out why. Please help.

```
import java.io.*;
class Specialchars
{
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException
    { 
        BufferedReader obj=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter one or more lines");
        String s=obj.readLine();

        int count1=0,count2=0,count3=0;

        for(int i=0; i<=s.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch=s.charAt(i);
            if(ch==' ')
            {
                count1++;
            }
            else    
            if(ch=='\t')
            {
                count2++;
            } 
            else    
            if(ch=='.')
            {
                count3++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of blank spaces is = "+count1);
        System.out.println("The number of tabs is = "+count2);
        System.out.println("The number of new lines is = "+count3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use

```
for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++)
```

instead of

```
for(int i=0; i<=s.length(); i++)
```

strings like arrays are enumarated starting from 0 so the last index is **length() - 1**